# What is happening under the covers in SSRS when you delete a history snapshot?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS, when you delete a history snapshot, what is really happening?
[image]

Is it running the stored procedure DeleteHistoryRecord?  If so, is it doing anything else?  We're looking to programmatically delete history snapshots older than X days and want to make sure we don't miss anything.  We thought the easiest way to do it would be to do the same thing that happens when you delete a history snapshot through the web interface.

Thanks!